# Identify the first referral URL for a set of customers in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Objective: Identify the original **referral URL**  for a customer.

I have a set of thouands of customers and each one has multiple sessions. For each customer I want to find the very first sessionid, and then from  that sessionid, I want to find the referral URL on the first viewed page within that session.

I have been able to do this with a single customer ID, but don't know how to programatically get this information for all customers.

Below is the SQL query that returns the right data for a single customer id.  How can I build a table that has two columns ("`Customer_ID`" and "`Original Referral URL`")?

```
SELECT 
    asciistr(HITS.REFERRER_URL), 
    HITS.REF_MARKER, 
    ACTS.REGISTRATION_DATE,  
    HITS.SESSION_ID, 
    hits.HIT_DATETIME    
FROM DB.CLICKSTRM_WMA_HITS hits
     INNER JOIN DB.D_Customers cus ON hits.customer_id = cus.customer_id
     INNER JOIN DB.ACCOUNTS ACTS ON CUS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACTS.ACCOUNT_ID     
WHERE HITS.IS_FIRST_VIEWED_PAGE = 1    
  AND CUS.ACCOUNT_ID = '999999999'  
GROUP BY HITS.HIT_DATETIME, ACTS.REGISTRATION_DATE, HITS.REF_MARKER, asciistr(hits.REFERRER_URL), HITS.SESSION_ID
ORDER BY HITS.HIT_DATETIME ASC
)WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ranking/analytic functions:

```
select *
from (SELECT asciistr(HITS.REFERRER_URL),HITS.REF_MARKER,      
             ACTS.REGISTRATION_DATE,HITS.SESSION_ID, hits.HIT_DATETIME,
             row_number() over (partition by cus.Account_Id
                                order by hits.sessionid, hits.IS_FIRST_VIEWED_PAGE desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from DB.CLICKSTRM_WMA_HITS hits INNER JOIN
           DB.D_Customers cus
           ON hits.customer_id = cus.customer_id INNER JOIN
           DB.ACCOUNTS ACTS
           ON CUS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACTS.ACCOUNT_ID
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

I think this is correct, if I followed your logic correctly.  Lowest session for each customer and then the one where IS_FIRST_VIEW_PAGE is 1.  I assume this is 0 for the other pages.

Comment: @user1601238 . . . I added your edits back in.  I don't know why they were rejected.

Comment: @user1601238 . . . What is the problem?